# Retrieve data from database with rest (jersey)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jersey

I am trying to retrieve data from  mysql database with Spring jdbc  and Jersey.My code is

The Dao is this one getUsers().  If i want to get all users it works fine i can show them on a jsp fine.

```
public List<User> getUsers() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Query DB for users");
     return jdbc.query("Select id,name,lname,username,"
        + "password,postcode,authority,email,"
        + "address,dateofbirth,city,country,"
        + "gender "
        + " from Users", new RowMapper<User>() {

        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            logger.debug(" query the user");
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            user.setLname(rs.getString("lname"));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            user.setPostcode(rs.getString("postcode"));         
            user.setAuthority(rs.getString("authority"));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            user.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            user.setDateofbirth(rs.getString("dateofbirth"));
            user.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
            user.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
            user.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));             
            return user;
        }

    });
}
```

Here is the resource class

```
   @Path("/user")
   public class UserResource {
      UserServiceWS userServicews = new UserServiceWS();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<User> getUserData() throws Exception {
    return userServicews.getUsers();
}
 }
```

so then here is my UserService Class

```
public class UserServiceWS {



@Autowired
UserDao userDao ;

public UserServiceWS() {
    try {
        getUsers();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<User> getUsers() throws Exception {
    return new ArrayList<User>(userDao.getUsers());
}
 }
```

So the problem is that i get nul pointer exception on userDao.getUsers().
What am i missing ?
here is the error code

> > HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> type Exception report
>
> message java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:397)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.org.projectClient.wsService.UserServiceWS.getUsers(UserServiceWS.java:29)
>     com.org.projectClient.resource.UserResource.getUserData(UserResource.java:23)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:172)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.68 logs. Apache Tomcat/7.0.68

the user class model

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
 import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

   @XmlRootElement
   public class User {

private int id;
@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 250)
private String username;
@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 250)
private String password;

       ...........
```

If i create a Map and add data there and retrieve i have no problem the web service works ok with no problem.?  But if i query the database then i have nullpointer.What am i missing ?
Thanks

after adding   as 11thdimension writes 
@Autowired to

```
@Autowired

  private UserServiceWS userServicews;
```

and to

```
 @Component 
  public class UserServiceWS {


    @Autowired  UserDao userDao ;
```

then i get

> HTTP Status 500 - A MultiException has 3 exceptions. They are:
>
> type Exception report
>
> message A MultiException has 3 exceptions. They are:
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions. 
>   They are:
>   1. org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
>   [com.org.projectClient.wsService.UserServiceWS] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.org.projectClient.resource.UserResource
>   errors were found
>   3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.org.projectClient.resource.UserResource
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:397)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> root cause
>
> A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
>   1. org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
>   [com.org.projectClient.wsService.UserServiceWS] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.org.projectClient.resource.UserResource
>   errors were found
>   3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.org.projectClient.resource.UserResource
>
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:252)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:160)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2270)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:652)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:116)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:116)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:116)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.org.projectClient.wsService.UserServiceWS] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver.getBeanFromSpringContext(AutowiredInjectResolver.java:101)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver.resolve(AutowiredInjectResolver.java:93)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:214)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:237)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:160)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2270)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:652)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:116)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:116)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:116)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.68 logs. Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
>   here is my  xml

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.projectClient" />


    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/testingdbs" id="dataSource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    </jee:jndi-lookup>

    <!-- <beans:bean id="messages" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
        <beans:property name="basename" value="com.spring.project.demo.messages.messages.properties" 
        /> </beans:bean> -->
```

....... so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you connect to DB?I think there you have your problem.

You have to fix your database connection.

Something is wrong there and you cannot retrieve your data.
It's not normal that you get data to a jsp and no data to your service.

Are you using Jndi or something else.Create a DaoManager to handle your connections.

Worst case create a simple open/close DB connection with password username driver details etc.

Only  to test your connection.

After creating that try it if this works then you have no DB connection for your service.

For DAOManager  look here [DAOManager](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-persistence/dao-manager.html)

for a simple connection look here [Simple Database Connection](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html)

or here

[Simple Database Connection 2](http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-connect-to-the-database-in-java).

Take care.

Comment: yes i am using jndi.I have to try again what you say.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line.

```
UserServiceWS userServicews = new UserServiceWS();
```

You're invoking constructor of the `UserServiceWS` instead of injecting it via `Spring`, so it's attribute `userDao` is not `Autowired`.

You should be autowiring it after making `UserSerivceWS` a `Component` or a Spring bean.

like below

```
@Component
public class UserServiceWS
```

And inject this as following.

```
@Autowired
private UserServiceWS userServicews;
```

Comment: i get javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:1. org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ...and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies and java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on  ......

Comment: Please include the change and the exception trace in the question.

Comment: @  11thdimension i have post it with the new error i have also look if spring cannot scan the package but it's ok

Comment: Make sure that `UserServiceWS` is annotated with `@Component` and is present on the package that spring is scanning.

Comment: `BeanNotFound` exception indicates that `UserServiceWS` bean was never created. That would mean that `base-package` or `@ComponentScan` doesn't contain the package for the `UserServiceWS` class.

Comment: I have try that also no